# How i can use InsertHtml?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

How i can insertHtml code in content ?

[image ckeditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHetK.png)

This method not inserting html code :

```
CKEDITOR.instances['update_content'].setData(info_content);
```

I tried:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['update_content'].editable().insertHtml('<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>');
```

but i got error:

```
ckeditor.js?v=3:407 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkReadOnly' of undefined
    at ckeditor.js?v=3:407
    at $.insertHtml (ckeditor.js?v=3:377)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (shop:3750)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I need dynamic content, I need change HTML code in CKEditor content every click button.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `insertHtml` after `editable()`, instead, you should use the following piece of code:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['update_content'].insertHtml('<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>');
```